# How do I create a dictionary where the keys are the values from a different dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given the following list of objects **a**:

```
a = [
    {"class": "math", "grade": 90},
    {"class": "english", "grade": 80},
    {"class": "science", "grade": 70},
]
```

How can I create a dictionary where the keys are the values of each object's "class" member within list "a" and the values are 0?

Desired data structure derived from "a":

```
b = {
    "math": 0,
    "english": 0,
    "science": 0
}
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm still wrapping my head around lists and dictionaries, I've just touched python yesterday.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have tried looking up how to access values in lists of dictionaries but results always show some form of dictionary comprehension which I don't yet understand. I'm afraid I might be stuck with syntax.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I see now what I need to read more on. thank you

Comment: `collections.defaultdict` is maybe what you want or `mydict.setdefault`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension like the following:

```
a = [
    {"class": "math", "grade": 90},
    {"class": "english", "grade": 80},
    {"class": "science", "grade": 70},
]

b = {x["class"]: 0 for x in a}
```

or **without** dictionary comprehension:

```
a = [
    {"class": "math", "grade": 90},
    {"class": "english", "grade": 80},
    {"class": "science", "grade": 70},
]

b = {}
for obj in a:
    b.setdefault(obj["class"], 0)
```

Comment: How do I rewrite that in a regular for loop? I haven't touched any list/dict comprehension yet

Comment: I did `for x in a:
        b[x["class"]] = 0` and it worked.

Comment: Added example without dictionary comprehension ^